# Bulk inserts with Sitecore Rocks

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

Is it possible to do a bulk insert with Sitecore Rocks?  Something along the lines of SQL's

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE2
```

If so, what is the syntax? I'd like to add an item under any other item of a given template type.

I've tried using this syntax:

```
 insert into (
 @@itemname,
 @@templateitem,
 @@path,
 [etc.]
 )   
 select  
'Bulk-Add-Item',
//*[@@id='{B2477E15-F54E-4DA1-B09D-825FF4D13F1D}'],
Path + '/Item',
[etc.]
```

To this, Query Analyzer responds:
    `"values" expected at position 440.`

Please note that I have not found a working concatenation operator.  For example,
    `Select @@item + '/value' from //sitecore/content/home/*`
just returns `'/value'`.  I've also tried ||, &&, and CONCATENATE without success.

There is apparently a [way of doing bulk updates with CSV](http://vsplugins.sitecore.net/Sitecore-Query-Analyzer-Import-CSV.ashx?HL=csv), but doing bulk updates directly from Sitecore Query Analyzer would be very useful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently you cannot do bulk inserts, but it is a really nice idea. I'll see what I can do.

Regarding the concatenation operator, this following works in the Query Analyzer:

```
select @Text + "/Value" from /sitecore/content/Home
```

This returns "Welcome to Sitecore/Value".

The `@@item` just returns empty, because it is not a valid system attribute.

Comment: Well considering Jakob created Sitecore Rocks, this appears to be the answer.